# Passing a String value to another Class in Java - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm fairly new to java, so I'm probably asking something that is either very easy to do or not possible.  I'm practicing exploiting vulnerable mobile apps using my own app (this is on a testing vulnerable app).  What I'm trying to achieve is taking a decrypted password I got from one class and pass that value into another class to decrypt a secret message.  I'm wondering if there's an easy way of doing this without having to redo a lot of my code.

I've hit my limit on my java knowledge to know if this can be done or how it can be done.  I don't know how useful it will be, but if required, I can post the code from my other two classes (Decrypt and Decrypt2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a non-private `getData()` method that when called by functions from other classes, returns the specific private data of your class. Be careful when using this though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get this a shot.  Since I'm not real familiar with this, I may need a tip on where to get started.  Would I create this method from the mainactivity class or the class that handles the decryption?

Also, when you say be careful when using this, what should I keep in mind so I can look out for?

Comment: Inside MainActivity class, create:

`public getData()
{
 return decryptedPassword;
}`

Then you can access your decrypted password as such:

`variable = MainActivityObject.getData();`

You have to be careful because this creates a possible vulnerability in your system that may be exploited to expose confidential information. If this is a home project, I wouldn't worry too much about it, though.

Comment: I am trying this, but I'm not sure I'm getting the syntax right.  I'm not too concerned about the vulnerability aspect of it since it's just for my own testing.  I'm using this as practice to improve my java coding skills and vulnerability exploitation. 

I'm not sure how to place the getData method so it gets the string from "decrypted1".  I think if I can figure that out, I'll be able to piece it all together.   If it's not too much trouble, can you take a piece of my code and show an example of how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Classes in java don't represent tangible things. They represent *blueprints* of tangible things.

So, a `class Person` isn't a person. It's a description of what people are like.

I can give you a sandwich. I can't give the notion of 'person' a sandwich.

Fortunately, this 'notion' concept includes the ability to create.

So, I can ask the notion of 'persons' as a concept: "Okay, make me a new person", and then hand that fresh new person a sandwich, no problem. Here, in java:

```
Sandwich sandwich = new Sandwich();
Person person = new Person(sandwich);
```

Here I first ask the conceptual notion of sandwiches: Can you make me a sandwich, and then I ask the conceptual notion of persons: Can you make ma a new person, and as we all know that persons are born with a sandwich in their hand, you need me to give you that sandwich so you can create the person, and voila, here it is.

The same would apply to your code, but 'Decrypt2' is an epically bad name. What does this represent? a data processor? a card in the user interface? Let's say it's that.

```
public class DecryptCard {
    private String pinToMd5;

    public DecryptCard(String pinToMd5) {
        this.pinToMd5 = pinToMd5;
    }
}
```

and then in the code you have that knows the pin (so, where you currently do `new Decrypt2()`), you'd do `new DecryptCard(decrypted1);`. One more problem: You don't have decrypted1 available at that exact spot. That's, again, part of the design of java here:

When `onClick` is called and the click is on R.id.exploit1, you figure out what the value is. And then the method ends, and all locally made variables disappear. And then you click on exploit2 and you no longer have the value.

Solution is trivial - make a field, store it there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That's helpful.  Yes, I know I have some bad names, i was just creating this for my own testing. If it was something I was going to give to anyone I'd clean up the names.  

So I made the changes you suggested.  I also removed the onClick call for R.id Exploit2 and just having it all run under the same click (to try to make this simple).  It's still not working, but it's possible that what the Decrypt2 class does may change your suggestion.  I'll update my post to show what the class does.